# Which STRM resolution Srtm2Osm.exe uses?

Tags: openstreetmap, elevation, contour, srtm, nasa

The piece of program [Srtm2Osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Srtm2Osm) uses SRTM elevation model from NASA to produce countour lines in OSM format.

Does it use the SRTM1 at 30m or SRTM3 at 90m?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @Vincenty! From the link you gave, it is mentioned in the **Limitations** section: _"Currently the tool only supports SRTM3 data."_ Although I can't confirm this as in the **Things Still To Do** section, it is mentioned that there were plans to _support SRTM1 data_...

Comment: Thanks, well spotted! I believe contour lines would be much nicer with STRM1 with no voids